# Do I have to run geth locally to access Rinkeby via web3.js?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, dapp-development, dapps, rinkeby

I have used truffle to a migrate some contracts to a local instance of `geth` that points at Rinkeby. The problem is that I'm behind a firewall, with little hope of getting port 8545 open, so now I can't get my dApp to use those contracts :(

However, do I have to use a local instance of `geth` to access contracts deployed to Rinkeby, via a dApp?

In other words, within my dApp, instead of:

`window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));`

Can I do something like:

`window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http:/api.rinkeby.io:8545"));`

...or some such like?

Comment: unfortunately, I won't be able to teswt this until Monday, but will `new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution here was to use [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) and set it to point at [rinkeby](https://www.rinkeby.io). Then the code just uses the current provider:

`window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to tell you how to do this in your exact code, but this page shows the various networks Infura provides: https://infura.io/docs/. The Rinkeby network is listed. That might work.