# Cannot connect to any ethereum networks using API key

Tags: web3js, ropsten, rinkeby

I followed a tutorial about how to connect web3 with ethereum networks.
I registered in infura.io and get all the urls. But when I try to connect to any network it is not connecting.When I print web3 connection status is always false. Below is my code and I use 1.0.0-beta.34 of web3

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY'));
web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, res){
     console.log("Network Type: "+res); //Displaying undefined
});
```

I tried with main net, ropsten and kovan. All are displaying `undefined`. I don't know what is the problem here. All example in web are showing these lines only. Can some one help me to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `v3` is a new end-point? my infura url doesn't have `v3` like yours

Comment: day before yesterday only I registered they provided with v3 only.  Also I tried with removing v3 but not worked. If you have working code can you share it please.

Comment: please refer to this by using metamask https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/do-i-have-to-run-geth-locally-to-access-rinkeby-via-web3-js?rq=1

Comment: My problem is I have to connect it in node js only

Comment: If your goal is just to get the network type then we can do it in another way

Comment: I can get into network when using Postman and in curl. My problem is I have to do automatic payments which can only possible in backends.

Comment: I mean, according to document https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-net.html#getnetworktype the `web3.eth.net.getNetworkType` is not 100% correct, then we need to find other way to get the correct one.

Comment: I can't even connect to any infura service using web3. I have setup private node for testing it works perfecty.

Comment: ah, okay! understood your problem.

Comment: it seems that you missing web3-net in your dependencies, please have a look on my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `web3-net` into your dependencies libs also and then it will work properly

```
  "dependencies": {
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.35",
    "web3-net": "1.0.0-beta.36"
  }
```

I run on my local and printout correctly as below

```
Network Type: rinkeby
```

sample source code: https://github.com/hadv/web3-client

```
const Web3 = require("web3")

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/5rhaTHgnqnbTEFj1S1Ya'));
web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, res){
      console.log("Network Type: "+res);
});
```

Comment: can you please post your code in github I'm struggling for more than 4 days

Comment: I included that too. My code is const Net = require('web3-net');  net = new Net(Net.givenProvider || 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxx');
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxx'));
        web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, res){
         console.log(err);
            console.log("Network Type: "+res); //Displaying undefined
        }); Still it is undefined

Comment: @e.k still using your code, but i edit to put the code in my answer; you need to update `package.json` and run `npm install` to update the lib then it will be fine

Comment: I put the code to github, please check it out: https://github.com/hadv/web3-client

Comment: I don't know what is the problem here. Thank you for your help. I give up.